# distributing cucmber junit5 tests in docker

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have cucumber project that is running on azure build and release pipelines.

I have installed docker and docker-compose and I am able to to open containers and grid using [`docker-selenium`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) through `docker-compose`

I would like to distribute cucumber tests , somewhat like [as explained here](https://nitinbhardwaj6.medium.com/selenium-grid-with-docker-c8ecb0d8404) . But in that link , it is explained using `testng` and I am using `junit5` with cucumber . How would I achieve that , specially the below part from the link , in conjunction with what we know about [cucumber parallelism in junit5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/README.md)?

```
@Parameters({"Port"})
@BeforeClass
public void initiateDriver(String Port) throws MalformedURLException {
            if(Port.equalsIgnoreCase("9001"))
    {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http:localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    else if(Port.equalsIgnoreCase("9002")){
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http:localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

As I understand , if I mention `cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true` , in `junit-platform.properties` , it will run parallely per feature file , how do I mention `port` to achieve below

1. Run each feature in one container
2. Is there a way to distribute each scenario of different feature files in separate container ?

Comment: You are mixing instructions from `cucumber-junit` and `cucumber-junit-platform-engine`. They're quite different. One is for JUnit 4, the other for the Junit Platform (JUnit 5).

Comment: I edited the link  to include only junit5 info . How can we achieve the above tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution for parallelizing `junit5` tests at scenario level so I used `testNG` with [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) in conjunction with [`cucumber-guice`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-guice/latest/io/cucumber/guice/package-summary.html). It worked out of the box and run parallel test at scenario level

Simply inlclude similar runner class in cucumber. My tests are further using `RemoteWebdriver` to open multiple instances on selenium grid. Make sure grid is up and running and node is registered to the grid.

```
import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        rerunAttempts = 1,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
        reportTargetDir = "build",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                glue = "com.test.stepdefs",                   
                publish = true,
                plugin = {
                        "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
        ))
class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
}
```

RemoteWebdriver config is

```
protected RemoteWebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException , IOException {
                   
                 Properties properties = new Properties();                
                ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();                
                  String hubURL = "http://192.168.1.7:65299/wd/hub";
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/amit/Desktop/amit/projects/misc/geckodriver");
                 
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);    
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.merge(capabilities);                 
                   driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options));
                   return driver.get();
        }
```

cucumber-guice related configs

```
    import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;    
    @ScenarioScoped
          public class Global {
          public RemoteWebDriver driver;
           
          public Global() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                driver = new DriverFactory().getManager();
               // getManager() should have driver from above createDriver()

          }
    }
```

Inject `Global` class in your stepdefs like below (do necessary imports). You can inject helper classes also and guice will have it available per scenario

```
 @Inject
   Global global;
 
  //then you can do
   global.driver.get(site);
```

pom for cucumber-guice

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Use below config , if you want to open the grid using `docker-compose` and point your tests to `http://localhost:65299/wd/hub` . Ports are according to the below file

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20210607
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "65299:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444


  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd let your CI run [a matrix of tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374086/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-example-file-for-all-cucumber-test/66404674#66404674). This matrix of tests can already run different jobs in parallel.
Each job in the matrix can execute either all tests or a slice of tests. You use tags to include or exclude certain tests on certain job configurations. This ensures that browser and OS specific problems are immediately apparent.

This also simplifies the problem somewhat. When you don't start a Selenium Grid with different browser types, you don't have to find a clever way to connect each test to the right browser.

Instead you each job only has to start a Selenium Grid with one browser type. Once the grid has been started each job can run tests in parallel by using multiple remote webdrivers.
Then all  you have to take care of is to make sure your tests don't try to use more browsers then the grid has available. This can be done by setting some configuration parameters:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

You have to get these [configuration parameters](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params) to your test execution. One way to do this would be to use a maven profile, but there are many other ways to do this:

```xml
        <profile>
            <id>parallelism</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <configurationParameters>
                                cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
                                cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
                                cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism={env.CONCURRENT_TESTS}
                                </configurationParameters>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

And you could tie this together like this:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./start-selenium-grid $BROWSER $CONCURRENT_TESTS
    - mvn test -Pparallelism
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - OS: Windows
        OS_VERSION: 10
        BROWSER: [Chrome, Firefox, Edge]
        CONCURRENT_TESTS: 4
      - OS: OS X
        OS_VERSION: Big Sur
        BROWSER: [Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari]
        CONCURRENT_TESTS: 2
```

So in summary. First run build jobs in parallel for different browsers. Then inside each job, run tests in parallel against multiple web drivers.

Comment: If lets say in matrix we open one container for one browser. Inside this job, how can we control that which feature file is to be run on which container. And even better if theres a way to control scenario.

Comment: That's what tags can be used for.