# How do I run my Cucumber Java project in parallel using different browsers?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

Right now, the test suite is able to run parallel using the same browsers. After I got some stellar advice on how to use the webdriver using DI (not shared, a new one per scenario), the guide on cucumber.io was just that: use Surefire, modify pom.xml, and done. Didn't need to touch the code. Also works using a Selenium Grid in Docker containers and it's been running on our Jenkins server since.

I kind of understand how it works, in that the different feature files are distributed over the threads.

How would this work using different browsers, though? I was thinking about getting a thread id from Surefire to fire off a different browser per thread, but then, only feature file A is running on thread 1, and feature file B is running on thread 2. I want thread 1 to run feature file A and B, and thread 2 to also run feature file A and B. (Not sure if I described this accurately, and I hope it gets the point across).

I did find one post on SO, but it was old and it uses a shared webdriver. It also seems to refer to an example on GitHub which wasn't linked.

Lack of knowledge doesn't make finding the right keywords to search for any easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374086/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-example-file-for-all-cucumber-test/66404674#66404674

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Anyway the feature files will be assigned to the threads based on their availability.