# Duplicit Data Tables in multiple feature files

Tags: python, testing, cucumber, gherkin, python-behave

I have multiple feature files that are all using the exact same data tables (apple, banana, mango).

```
Feature: Something

  Scenario Outline: Something

    Given something <FRUIT>
    When something
    Then something

@apple
Examples:
  | FRUIT |
  | apple |

@banana
Examples:
  | FRUIT |
  | banana |

@mango
Examples:
  | FRUIT |
  | mango |
```

Is there a a way to have these data tables specified just once instead of having them in each feature file?
Maybe have a separate file with just the tables and then refer to it in each feature file?
We use the tags to specify which fruit to use at runtime.

Comment: This does not make much sense nor do the Tags used.

Comment: You've used fruit as a generic example to ask your question. If this happens to be a browser, you'll want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374086/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-example-file-for-all-cucumber-test/66404674#66404674

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, this is not what scenario outlines are used for. It seems what you are trying to do is pass a single parameter when the test is launched (i.e. "banana") and run that single case. Scenario Outlines are to run ALL rows of the table in a loop. For what you need, you could either create a custom data type (i.e. Enum) with all allowed fruits, or a simple string patterns with OR'ed constants (i.e. "apple|banana|mango").